# CryptoPP generates invalid keys RSA

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, crypto++

I'm trying to encrypt some text with RSA in c++,

when encrypting I'm generating `n, e, d` but when trying to decrypt, the private key initializer says the keys are invalid...

So I built a code that generates the keys and then tries to initialize a private key object right after that and it says the keys are still invalid:

```
int main()
{
    
    CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction params;
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(prng, 2048);
    params.SetPublicExponent(65537);

    const CryptoPP::Integer& n = params.GetModulus();
    const CryptoPP::Integer& p = params.GetPrime1();
    const CryptoPP::Integer& q = params.GetPrime2();
    const CryptoPP::Integer& d = params.GetPrivateExponent();
    const CryptoPP::Integer& e = params.GetPublicExponent();

    CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey privk;
    privk.Initialize(n, e, d);
}
```

The program crashes to: `InvertibleRSAFunction: input is not a valid RSA private key`

Comment: `GenerateRandomWithKeySize()` cannot be used to generate a key with a public exponent of 65537, but only 17. If the public exponent is changed afterwards, the posted error message is triggered, if it is changed before, this change is ignored and a key with the public exponent of 17 is generated. To generate a key with a user-defined size and public exponent, a different overload must be used, namely `privk.Initialize(prng, 2048, 65537);`.

Comment: @Topaco that is an answer, not a comment. Also, the `Initialize` must return an exception since 65537 may not be relatively prime with Euler toitent ( or lambda).

Comment: Lots of libraries now default to a public exponent being the fifth prime of Fermat, F4 or 65537 (`010001` in hexadecimals shows the reason for the value). However, CryptoPP is an older library; they may have kept to an old default.

Comment: @kelalaka That doesn't make much sense to me; clearly the public exponent is set beforehand even if it is 17. Most RSA key pair generation is performed with F4 set, and the given answer also assumes this. You can always retry during key pair generation anyway; RSA already has an nondeterministic running time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is that you modified the exponent after the key was already generated.

```
params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(prng, 2048);
params.SetPublicExponent(65537);
```

Actually the key was generated in the first line with e = 17. Try to change the line order.

```
params.SetPublicExponent(65537);
params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(prng, 2048);
```